# Clojure maps vs. "Real" database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, clojure

What are the strengths and weaknesses of using clojure maps vs. a real (eg mysql) database?  Obviously it depends on the number of records and the width of the tables, but I assume at some point the presumed efficiency/performance of a real DB outweighs the latency in calling into an external system.  For a modern PC (eg several GHz and GB ram) where is this limit in terms of size of the database?  If I'm doing really basic queries which don't involve a lot of joins, can the clojure map do as well as a real db?

What is a real database doing under the covers that clojure maps aren't?  Why can't I have a clojure map that contains 10 million entries, or can I?  What about performance, or multithreading, etc?  Presumably in the db there are hash maps and O(1) or O(log N) algorithms going on underneath, similar to how clojure maps and other stuff are implemented.

thanks

Comment: That's a dozen questions in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're kind of comparing apples and oranges here - Clojure maps are low-level data structures, an RDBMS such as MySQL is a full-blown software application that provides a whole host of features. Honestly, I think a comparison of the two in terms of low-level performance characteristics is a bit misguided. Instead consider the high-level features provided by each:

**Clojure maps** are in-memory data structures. You stick [key, value] pairs into the map, and you can look values up by their key. They're obviously limited by the available physical memory on your system, and you lose them when the system shuts down. They're great if you want a short-lived key-value store for a reasonably-sized data set.

An **RDBMS** typically lives in its own process, which you use a network protocol to communicate with (though some can be embedded in-process). It provides lots of features that low-level data structures don't such as access control, replication, etc. but probably the most important are:

- On-disk persistence of your data.
- A high-level language for querying and updating the content of your data store.

Because of its transactional and persistence capabilities that an RDBMS has, it's going to be much slower than an in-memory map. It's also going to be a lot more effort on your part to set up, configure, and maintain.

The choice of which one to use really comes down to what features your application requires. If you care about persistence or a high-level query language, then you're going to need to look into an RDBMS, or some more recent database technologies such as Mongo, Couch, or Datomic.

Comment: I should probably clarify the specific application I had in mind.  In the case of a electronic design tool (eg EDA, CAD, etc.,) where you have ~1k of components on a PCB and perhaps 10k components in a library, a large netlist, etc.  Each component has a number of properties, footprints, vendors, etc.  Sometimes it needs to be in memory and accessed quickly; other times when you shut down or email your design to someone it needs to be persistent.  Often times in the design process you're selecting or filtering components.  So it smells like a DB, but it could be implemented in maps.

Comment: Sounds to me like a caching layer over a key/value store (e.g. MongoDB).